# Binding input type range on input number with AngularJS 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, range

I'm facing a strange problem : i m trying to bind an input range with an input number. I m aware that input range return string and input number allow only number as value.

So I've found this workaround who work nicely with AngularJS 1.1 but not with 1.2 ... The value is empty.

```
app.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (attrs.type.toLowerCase() !== 'number') {
                return;
            } //only augment number input!
            ctrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                return value ? parseFloat(value) : null;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SanderElias/qb44R/

Any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have found a workaround : watch the range and force it to return int.

```
    $scope.easy = {quantite:0,patient:0,quantite_new:0};
    $scope.$watch('easy.patient', function() {
        console.log($scope.easy.patient);
        $scope.easy.patient  = parseInt($scope.easy.patient);
    });
```

I had to create an object "easy" because $watch seems to not work with normal variables ... Anyway this do the work so I guess it's ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it and it worked for me. we can use ***ng-change*** and attach event handlers for synchronizing the values of relative slider and input type number. e.g

```
<input type="range" ng-model="slider.value" ng-change="sliderToNumber()"
min="0" max="100" step="1" />

<input type="number" ng-model="inputNum.value"
ng-change="numberToSlider()" min="0" max='100' />
```

and in the controller like this

```
$scope.sliderToNumber = function() {

    $scope.inputNum.value = parseInt($scope.slider.value);
};

$scope.numberToSlider = function() {

    $scope.slider.value = $scope.slider.value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a alternative to your first try on modifying the input-number:
(tested with Angularjs 1.4.4)

```
app.directive('input', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (attrs.type.toLowerCase() === 'range') {
                // change output of range to number.
                ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                    var valueAsFloat = parseFloat(value);
                    var returnValue;
                    if (isFinite(valueAsFloat)) {
                        returnValue = valueAsFloat;
                    } else {
                        // don't change model
                        returnValue = ctrl.$modelValue;
                    }
                    return returnValue;
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

this modifies all input-elements with type="range" so that they write a float value to the model - or if the conversion goes wrong - do not change the modelvalue.